# What are my chances of admission to high-ranked PhD programs given my mediocre GRE taken in 2018 (154 V, 153 Q),but Master's degree in Yale?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, gre, canada

So hey everyone! Basically I have been lately considering applying to a PhD in Political Science, 2 years after I finished my Master's degree in an Ivy League institution in a related field. As it turns out, most of PhD programs require GRE, which in my case is 1) old but still relevant (taken in 2018) and 2) somewhat mediocre (154 V, 153 Q). Yet, this is the score that got me into Yale 4 years ago.

My current calculation is that my Master's degree from an Ivy and my academic performance there may bolster my application. GPA was not calculated but overall performance was good, way better than my bachelor's. Besides, I hope PhD admissions will take it into account that I took GRE 5 years ago. Hopefully I'll get some discount as an international applicant too ;).

However, I keep worrying about my score especially when I see something like "average score of our students is [more than mine]". I am planning to apply to schools like Stanford, a couple of Ivies, NYU, and some lower ranked schools. In addition, I am considering Canadian schools, like McGill, UofT, and UBC.  What do you think my chances are to get admission to the schools of my choice given my background?

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. We can’t estimate your odds of admission, see the linked page for the rationale. If it’s possible to boil this down to something of more general interest (“how does X affect my application?”), you might [edit] your post to ask the boiled down version instead. Good luck.